# Crux Framework - Dúvida ao criar meu próprio componente

Tags: crux-framework

Estive seguindo a documentação presente no site Crux Framework e tentei fazer aquele [exemplo básico](http://files.cruxframework.org/crux53/index.html#sec_tools_schcema4) de componente que é apresentado lá. É um exemplo simples mas sinceramente estou começando ainda e tive problemas para criar ele. Eu consigo este exemplo do tutorial implementado e funcionando para poder analisar via código e possivelmente identificar o que posso ter esquecido/errado?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Adicione a pergunta sua tentativa, para facilitar que te ajudem.

Comment: Obrigado Diego. Eu fiz uma nova tentativa, agora seguindo a implementação de um componente(TopMenuDisposal) já existente em crux-widgets. Uma interface TopMenuDisposal, seus controllers (Small/Large) e o XML .xdevice.xml. As anotações são as mesmas que o componente possui. De fato, uma cópia para ver um componente existente funcionando vindo de um pacote do meu projeto. Generate Schemas.launch foi executado e um novo arquivo .xsd é gerado. Mas ao executar Start CodeServer.launch, ele lança exceção.

Comment: Ao executar Start CodeServer.launch gera a exceção: Error parsing cross device file: [topMenuDisposalLarge], for DeviceAdaptive interface [br.com.crux.client.reuse.widget.menudisposal.TopMenuDisposal]. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null. 

Caso saiba ou tenha alguma sugestão, agradeço sua atenção.

Obrigado Diego. Abçs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversos componentes nas bibliotecas [crux-widgets](https://github.com/CruxFramework/crux-widgets) e [crux-smart-faces](https://github.com/CruxFramework/crux-smart-faces) que podem servir de exemplo para te ajudar a montar o seu. Esses componentes estão disponíveis no github.

Um bom exemplo, similar ao mostrado no tutorial, é o componente MenuTabsDisposal. [Aqui](https://github.com/CruxFramework/crux-widgets/tree/master/src/main/java/org/cruxframework/crux/widgets/client/disposal/menutabsdisposal) você pode ver a implementação das interfaces do componente e [Aqui](https://github.com/CruxFramework/crux-widgets/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/cruxframework/crux/widgets/client/disposal/menutabsdisposal) você pode ver os arquivos com a declaração visual dos componentes.

Repare que eles devem estar contidos no mesmo pacote. Neste caso, estou enviando dois links porque esse é um projeto maven e as classes java estão debaixo da estrutura src/main/java e os arquivos de tela estão debaixo de src/main/resources, mas observe que os arquivos estão todos dentro do mesmo pacote.

Se esses exemplos não forem suficientes, por favor poste o código que está tentando montar, que eu posso te ajudar a identificar onde está o erro.

---

### **EDIT**

Sobre este erro apontado no comentário, me parece que o Crux não está encontrando o arquivo de view do componente (no caso, o topMenuDisposalLarge.xdevice.xml).

Verifique se este se encontra no mesmo pacote da interface do componente (no caso, a TopMenuDisposal).

Caso o projeto esteja usando uma estrutura onde os fontes estejam separados dos resources (como um projeto maven, onde temos src/main/java e src/main/resources), verifique se a pasta onde se encontra o arquivo de view (.xdevice.xml) se encontra no classpath do launcher executado.

---

### **EDIT 2**

Ontem (15/12/2015) foi lançada uma nova versão do crux (5.4.0). Junto com esta versão, foi criado um plugin do crux para o maven (crux-maven-plugin).

Se você estiver trabalhando com o maven, sugiro atualizar para a nova versão e tentar usar o plugin. Ele facilita muito a configuração do seu pom e acredito que pode auxiliar a resolver problemas como esse que você relatou (configuração de classpath ao executar codeserver, devmode etc).

A documentação dessa nova versão está aqui: http://files.cruxframework.org/crux54/index.html

---

### **EDIT 3**

Sobre a geração dos XSDs... Juntamente com o crux 5.4, foi lançado um plugin do crux para o maven (crux-maven-plugin). Os schemas são gerados agora pelo plugin. Dá uma olhada no manual da versão 5.4 que descreve como  usar:

http://files.cruxframework.org/crux54/index.html#sec_tools_schcema

Basicamente, basta configurar o novo plugin no pom.xml e chamar mvn crux:generate-xsds

Abcs.

Thiago

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas considerações Thiago e peço desculpas a demora em responder. Eu preferi tentar algumas vezes durante essa semana mas não consegui.
Adicionei uma interface do componente desejado como abordado na documentação e seu respectivo controller sequindo de uma interface .xdevice.xml. Coloquei as anotações necessárias e executei Generate Schemas.launch. Isso gera um arquivo xsd da biblioteca desejada contendo o componente a ser usado e visível na IDE. Pra mim, isso é o necessário para ter o componente, certo?
Obrigado Thiago

Comment: Por fim, arrisquei COPIAR + COLAR o componente TopMenuDisposal presente na biblioteca crux-widgets. Uma tentativa de fazer um componente pronto executar vindo dos pacotes do meu projeto e ver se funcionaria. Assim mesmo não rodou. Estou interpretando algo errado, seguindo o caminho errado e esquecendo alguma coisa essencial. Ao executar Start CodeServer.launch gera a exceção: 
Error parsing cross device file: [topMenuDisposalLarge], for DeviceAdaptive interface [br.com.crux.client.reuse.widget.menudisposal.TopMenuDisposal].
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

Comment: Adicionei uma edição sobre este erro. Por favor, veja se isso ajuda

Comment: Fiz como sugeriu. Agora criei uma nova aplicação com a versão nova ainda trabalhando com maven. Segui o Quickstart do site e conferi na nova documentação as configurações. Na conf. manual pude acompanhar os códigos que foram gerados automaticamente. Na versão anterior apareciam os erros ao tentar usar os .xsd criados. Antes existia um arquivo Generate Schemas.launch. Agora não existe mais. Mas os .xsd`s não são mais gerados na pasta /target/xsd quando crio uma Factory para um componente desejado. O pom veio configurado automaticamente. Tenho que habilitar isso? Não achei na documentação. Obg!

Comment: Percebi que ao salvar um arquivo a página não compila em segundo plano. Agora eu altero, salvo e atualizo a página no navegador. 
Os arquivos estão como segue: 
http://s4.postimg.org/ki52pwf99/crux_hello_app.png
http://s30.postimg.org/8nvw01f8h/crux_hello_app2.png
http://s11.postimg.org/crvh6ljf7/crux_hello_app3.png

Comment: Oi Thales, desculpa a demora para responder. Quebrei a mão em dezembro e fiquei afastado do trabalho... Sobre a geração dos XSDs, eu adicionei um comentário à minha resposta. Já sobre a compilação ela realmente mudou na 5.4. Recompilar automaticamente a cada alteração estava lento para projetos grandes e o compilador do GWT utilizado na versão 5.3 não permitia compilar de forma incremental. Por isso fazíamos a compilação em background. No crux 5.4, atualizamos para a ultima versão do GWT que já é capaz de compilar sozinha no momento do refresh caso haja alteração.